# Gitlab Wiki same page links

Tags: markdown, gitlab

How do I use same page links in the Gitlab wiki? For example:

```
Contents

 - heading1 ---> this should move the page to heading 1
 - heading2
 - heading3
 - heading4

HEADING 1
```

Basically I am trying to create a page like Wikipedia where you can navigate a single page using a table of contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been added in this [pull request](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/1147).

It generates `toc_x` anchors, with x incremented for each new header.

If you define a link like:

```
 [My link to third header](#toc_3)
```

It will link you to the current page third header (no matter what level that header is).